# What does this error on Datepicker means? And how can it be resolved?

Tags: python, django

I am having this error after I click the update button from my modal.
https://www.screencast.com/t/NOJr22Jyip
Other data I submit is ok only this datepicker has an issue.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xl-12">
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <div class="form-group bmd-form-group is-focused">
       <label class="bmd-label-floating" for="birthday">Birthday</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control Dtpicker" id="birthday" name="birthday" value="{{employee.birthday}}" >
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Views.py

```
def save_employee_update(request):          
    bday = request.POST['birthday']          
    employee = Employee.objects.get(employee_id=emp_id)        
    employee.birthday = bday        
    employee.save()    
    # return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form, 'successful_submit': True})
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

JS for it.

```
 $(".Dtpicker").datetimepicker({
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
    useCurrent: false,
    icons:
        {
            next: 'fa fa-angle-right',
            previous: 'fa fa-angle-left'
        }
})
$(document).on("click", "#employee_update_btn", function () {
        if ($('#birthday').val() == ''){
            return
        }
 });
```

After I click the update button the alert shows up but when I tried to print the value of birthday it does not contain anything. And That error show up.

Comment: is that your bday data in `YYYY-MM-DD` format?
it seems that bday  is ''

Comment: yes it is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: is '' into bday?I think  you pass '' into view.

Comment: what do you mean? Anyway it is saved on the DB but i think the problem is on the JS since on click of employee_update_btn it does return the value of birthday.

Comment: your error in the picture says that you got empty string somewhere in js code instead `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Yeah, and i don't know really which part of the JS i messed up.

Comment: use `debugger;` in your js code to debug it in inspect view(F12) in browser

Comment: Thanks, found the cause of issue. Some syntax on the index.html is missing for the format of the datepicker.